# UIButton on/off stutters when it's target selector performs UIGraphics drawHierarchy code on main thread

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, uikit, core-graphics

I have a UIButton whose target performs some `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` `drawHierarchy` steps to create `UIImage` from a few views.

```
let toPrint = cell.contentView
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(toPrint.bounds.size, true, 0)
toPrint.drawHierarchy(in: toPrint.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
if let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() {
   images.append(image)
}
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

This causes the UIButton's on/off state change animation to stutter.

In iOS when once taps a UIButton, the knob animates from one position to another (off/on -> left to right knob animation). This iOS animation stutters when I perform my `drawHierarchy` code.

Is there a way to fix this WITHOUT adding a delay?

Comment: If I understand correctly, try to -> Tap the button -> call animation button func -> in completion handler of animation call the func of drawHierarchy... Or do you want to start animation and drawHierarchy simultaneously?

Comment: @Fabio sorry I think you misunderstood my issue. The animation isn't mine. It's the default iOS animation where when a switch is tapped, the nab automatically animates from one side to another. I don't have control over this animation.

Comment: Oooooo sorry, happy Easter :)

Comment: @Fabio no worries. Happy Easter to you too!

Comment: Maybe try running this code in runloop common modes.